# Como Actualizar o insertar los datos de una tabla a otra tabla en una misma base datos en SQL

Tags: sql-server

Buenos dias una ves mas requiero se acostumbrada ayuda saludo

el problema que tengo es que quiero actualizar una tabla con los datos de otra tabla siempre en la misma base de datos en SQL pero por razone de la vida no me ha actulizado este es el script que siempre utilizo :

```
UPDATE TablaDestino SET TablaDestino.ID = (Select CompoActulizar FROM TablaOrigen AS m)
```

pero no me actuliza queria saber si me podian ayudar y como seria cuando quiero actualizar mas de un campo

gracias .
Bendiciones

Comment: Ejemplo de tu SQL: `UPDATE TablaDestino SET TablaDestino.ID = 1234`  creo que te haría falta un `WHERE` para evitar que te actualizara toda la tabla. Porque con esta consulta lo que estás haciendo es ponerle al campo `TablaDestino.ID` el valor que recuperas de `TablaOrigen.CampoActualizar`

Comment: La tabla destino esta vacía   y quiero actualizar el ID es decir que todos los id de la origen me los ponga en la tablaDestino

Comment: Entonces si quieres migrar todos los ID's de Orgien a Destino....
Si Destino está vacía, no tendrías que usar `UPDATE`, sino `INSERT`

Answer (score 2):

Cuando necesites ejecutar un scrit en una sola base de datos utiliza:

```
USE[BaseDatos]
```

Y debajo de él, todo el script a ejecutar en esa base.

Otra opción es indicar completamente el nombre de la tabla, base de datos + esquema + nombre, es decir:

```
TuBase.TuEsquema.TuTabla

DBPrueba.dbo.Tabla
```

Cabe destacar que "dbo" es el esquema estandar, en caso de no haberlo especificado cuando creabas la tabla.

En tu situación creería que el error no está en que base estás usando sino mas bien en tu script.

Tu sub-select puede devolver muchos valores, por lo que debes utilizar un Top(1), para que solo devuelva un resultado, de la siguiente forma:

```
UPDATE TablaDestino 
SET TablaDestino.ID = (SELECT TOP(1) CompoActulizar FROM TablaOrigen AS m)
```

Espero la explicación te haya ayudado a resolver tu problema, saludos.

Comment: Hola Rostan gracias por tu aporte  al ejecutar ese  script me no me actualiza datos

Comment: Si no te actualiza, verifica el alcanzce de tu tabla, al ser ID, quizas tengas problemas de clave foranea por lo que al actualizarlo, debes actualizar el campo referencia en las otras tablas.

Comment: no tiene ninguna llave el campo

Answer (score 0):

Actualizar varios campos:

```
UPDATE TablaDestino 
SET TablaDestino.Campo1 = (SELECT CompoActulizar1 FROM TablaOrigen),  
TablaDestino.Campo2 = (SELECT CompoActulizar2 FROM TablaOrigen)
```

¿El por qué no te actualiza?

Ha [contestado](/a/158768/20001) el compañero [Rostan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/23943/rostan)

**EDICIÓN TRAS ESTE COMENTARIO**

> La tabla destino esta vacía y quiero actualizar el ID es decir que todos los id de la origen me los ponga en la tablaDestino – Jose [hace 10 minutos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/158763/como-actualizar-o-insertar-los-datos-de-una-tabla-a-otra-tabla-en-una-misma-base?noredirect=1#comment298296_158763)

```
INSERT INTO tabla2(columna1, columna2, columna3, ...)
SELECT columna1, columna2, columna3, ...
FROM tabla1
WHERE concicion;
```

Como no has pasado una estructura de tus tablas, espero que este ejemplo te sirva

Comment: gracias solucionado

Comment: Lo habitual si una respuesta ha solucionado tu problema es marcarla como respuesta correcta, mas información del funcionamiento de [es.so] haciendo el [tour]